# jQueryUI: restrict container height on drag and drop element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have achieved a drag & drop functionality using the jquery UI.

Here is the js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/metm0v0f/) for it.

When I drop a div from one div to another div, I wanted to restrict the height to increase. I have tried to restrict with the css classes:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

but it is still increasing the height. Can anyone please help me to make the container dimensions fixed?

Comment: Look like your drag and drop function in jsfiddle not working.

Comment: You can restrict the height by using max-height and overflow-y to scroll

Comment: @Mr.x just tested it, I can drag & drop easily

Comment: @cdoshi, still it is not restricting. http://jsfiddle.net/metm0v0f/7/

Comment: Insert max-height condition under .dbContainer1, .dbContainer2, .dbContainer3 block

Comment: @AlphaGeek What exactly you require, the red dots container height to be fixed inspite of additional elements being dropped into it and using scroll to scroll them?

Answer (score 2):

Just add these 2 lines to the dbContainer1,dbContainer2 classes:

```css
.dbContainer1 {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    border: dotted 1px red;
    /*add the following lines*/
    height:250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.dbContainer2 {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    border: dotted 1px green;
    /*add the following lines*/
    height:250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```